# Connectivity Plugin Stream Presenting Wrong Network State

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am adding more networking state aware logic to a Flutter App I have developed using the [Connectivity Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity)

After much testing I discovered there are times when the connectivityResult provided by the stream exposed by the plugin is incorrect.

This code is contained within a BLoC Provider Class.

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';


  final Connectivity _networkStatus = Connectivity();


  _networkStatus.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_updateConnectionStatus);


  Future<void> _updateConnectionStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async {

    if (Constants.DISPLAY_LOGS)
      Utilities().displayLog('_updateConnectionStatus, result passed: $result');

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000));

    var _connectionStatus = await _networkStatus.checkConnectivity();

    if (Constants.DISPLAY_LOGS)
      Utilities().displayLog('_updateConnectionStatus, after 3 seconds: ${_connectionStatus.toString()}');

    switch (_connectionStatus) {

      case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
      case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
      {
        networkConnected = true;

        if (_currentFirebaseUser == null)
          if (!_signingInAnonymously)
            await _signInAnonymously();
      }
        break;

      case ConnectivityResult.none:
        networkConnected = false;
        break;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

The diagnostic logging shows an example of the issue:

***** _updateConnectionStatus, result passed: ConnectivityResult.wifi

***** _updateConnectionStatus, after 3 seconds: ConnectivityResult.none

You can see that the Stream event passed a status showing that wifi was active, but it was not, I had disabled wifi, that action caused the Stream to trigger an event with the wrong status indication.

Then, after a 3 second delay, a direct call to _networkStatus.checkConnectivity provided an accurate state of network connectivity.

My question is whether my usage is proper. If so, then I wanted to inform the community of the issue.

Comment: You also can open an issue on GitHub by [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/labels/p%3A%20connectivity) link. It is an official bug tracker for this plugin.